# Can I control my ID and Name tags in asp. Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

When I use asp.net controls, (like inputs), I specify an ID in the markup; however, when I deploy the solution it's been prefixed with some automatically generated ASP.net identifiers with my original ID appended on the end.

I don't want to use the server side tag workaround present in other SO questions to give my jQuery a fixed ID to latch onto because it discourages using external JS files. Does 4.0 give you more control over your IDs?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does prevent you to fix IDs in asp.Net. It has always been possible (from the 1st version). It is even part of the ASP.Net internal behavior.

Comment: I misread your question. You don't want to use server side tag. So is it a question related to Html/jquery? And what are you calling a bug, if you don't say waht does not works

Comment: In previous versions of asp. Net, your ID is generated for you.

Comment: You should really precise what you mean. I guess you are talking about the fact that a control will produce a **client** id equals to the concatenation of all parents's IDs + the server side Id. But it's only a guess. Follow sean's answer if I'm right.

Comment: It's been edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your control.

Alternatively, and this has always been possible, you can output the control's HTML ID straight into your javascript:

```
$('#<%= textBox1.ClientID %>').hide();
```

`ClientIDMode` reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: A 3rd alternative is to use some dummy css class to "mark" the controls. You can, for example, write a textbox like this: `<asp:textbox runat="server" id="someid" cssclass="firstnamebox" />`. Then, you can select the textbox using the css class from jQuery: `$(".firstnamebox").val("some value")`. This will let you avoiding tweaking the ids, or using some kind of inline code. The small glitch, is that you will lost some milliseconds because of the slower performance compared to an ID selector (probably not an issue)

Comment: Thanks Sean, the first part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4+, you can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) on any Control to specifiy how the ID is generated.

Comment: The op said he does **not** want to use server side tags. So your answer does not applies. (I wouldn't be surprised if this is still what the OP wanted).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net has a [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) on all Controls now since 4.0 that allows you to have full control over your ID's.